# Language Barriers

Tags: discussion, help-center

I recently came across a post in a review queue that was completely written in another language. I couldn't understand it, and couldn't translate it using the internet, so I left it as is. How does our community handle this issue? Is there a procedure in the Help Center? *Actually, I'm slightly confused as to how this user ended up on our site, considering everything's in English here and this user likely does not speak English.*

Comment: Related: [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewT. Quite enlightening!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally what we do if we can't translate easily ourselves is close it, if it is a question, and ask the poster to redo it in English, as Music.SE is an English speaking site. For answers, we leave a comment asking them to edit into English and then we delete the post. Once edited it can easily be undeleted.

Interestingly, using google translate I can see what they were trying to get at, but it isn't easy to figure out correctly, so I have deleted it for now.

Comment: Well, you're smarter than I am! I used Google Translate and still didn't know what they were getting at. I just flagged it as "very low quality" and "unlikely to be salvaged" (or whatever the wording is).